# Mounting Synology NAS with NFSv4 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, 22.04, fstab, nfs, nas

I'd been using Debian for ages, but had hardware issues where certain devices (mostly audio devices) never worked. I switched to Ubuntu 22.04 recently and set up my user with the same uid and gid as the user on my NAS. However, I am unable to edit files on the NAS.

**fstab**

```
#192.168.10.10:/volume1/share /media/nas nfs4 rw,hard,rsize=8192,nconnect=16,wsize=8192,timeo=14,vers=4 0 0
192.168.10.10:/volume1/share /media/nas nfs auto,rw,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

The top commented out entry was the one I used on Debian, and the bottom is the current one I am playing with. Most things I read are showing similar options to use. I can browse and view files, I just cannot write.

**Synology NAS IDs**

```
uid=1026(user1) gid=1026(user1) groups=1026(user1)
```

**Ubuntu IDs**

```
uid=1026(user1) gid=1026(user1) groups=1026(user1),24(cdrom),100(users)
```

I'm sure I am doing something obviously wrong but nothing I find via Google has helped!

My latest attempt has everything owned by admin:users and chmod 664 which seems to work via SSH but not when I use Ubuntu Desktop to browse the paths. It thinks folders are files :(

**Update 1:**
So doing a `chmod 755` instead seems to have solved the file/folder issue on the desktop. Is this the best way though to do this and have all files owned by `admin:users` ??

Comment: Have you seen [this resource on NFS](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS) from Synoloogy?

Comment: @graham I have seen that, yes. I don't believe it offers anything for me though. I have the share working. My issue is writing and and ownership of files etc.

Comment: another thing to consider - is NFS the right file system for you? Mostly ext4 (or BTRFS) would be used for access using Linux. My Synology DS220j NAS uses 2 x 4TB drives in an SHR RAID and I can mount shares easily in my 22.04 and 23.10 instances using cifs with uid=100 and gid=500

Comment: I did also investigate CIFS over NFS on Linux and most if not all posts seemed to reply suggesting the user used NFS for Linux. Since I use it to stream, I was under the impression NFS was preferred here. However, it has been working with NFS fine. I just keep having these ownership issues when files are created on the NAS directly and then I try to access them from Linux (sometimes Windows too). I had thought using the same uid/gid as the user on the NAS would solve that.

Comment: Synology recommends [this](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/tutorial/Which_file_system_should_I_use_to_create_a_volume) for general use. I did originally have a WD MyBookLive NAS attached to windoze PCs (before moving entirely to Ubuntu) and the files were then moved to the Synology NAS but I don't recall any issues with accessing those files and I can access them all now. I'm not familiar with streaming services on Synology so can't usefully comment on that aspect. IDK but are cifs and NFS are compatible on the same volume?

Comment: I am using Btrfs as my file system already.